# A-Frame: Cursor is fixed and not moving in VR

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

I use gazed based controls with the A-frame cursor component to navigate. While it works perfectly in my browser on desktop and mobile, the cursor is fixed and not moving in VR mode (not working on Google cardboard and neither with the Oculus browser or Firefox Reality).

Here's the code I use:

```
<a-camera>
  <a-cursor
    cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 2000"
    position="0 0 -1"
    geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.01; radiusOuter: 0.02"
    material="color: red; shader: flat">
  </a-cursor>
</a-camera>
```

I use the following scripts in the head of my HTML:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.3/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@5/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-layout-component@5.3.0/dist/aframe-layout-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-template-component@3.2.1/dist/aframe-template-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-proxy-event-component@2.1.0/dist/aframe-proxy-event-component.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a bug that has been recently fixed. It will ship in 1.0.4 but you can use master builds in the meantime:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@130f5846ac7cb99dff0e30d703c15c046c066529/dist/aframe-master.min.js

Comment: Thanks a lots. Works now :). I moved to version 1.01 for the time being and will install 1.04 as soon as it has been released.